# How to display videos in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, video

Hello I am writing a WPF application which should plays a set of videos which should played fullscreen.

i tried to work with some VLC lib's but they did not worked for me.

then i moved to mediaelement - when i start playing a video i always get a black flicker

loading multiple videos was a huge performance loss - videos stuttered...

any recommendations how to resolve this issue ?

i plan do the following programm:

the kinect detects people which move along --> the programm plays a video 
if people stop and watch the screen --> the programm plays a extended version

UPDATE: checked vlc.net and it will also have a BLACK frame at the beginnign -- ARGH !
UPDATE: seems like the first frame is always black!? hmmm (added timer and started the video 1 second after it was loaded - still have the black frame ...)

Comment: Just to clarify...you tried using this did you ? http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my application : i use vvvv.org and send my data trough a UDP connection - i handle the video stuff in this VVVV application - works great ... i am very disapointed by microsofts video support ... i hope this will get better in the future thx anyways :)